# postgres can't access a 777 file

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I'm trying to dump a csv file into postgres table and I've logged in to postgres shell with
`sudo -u postgres psql` command.
And my file's permission is like:

> -rwxrwxrwx

But postgres gives me the `Permission denied` error.

I'm using this command in postgres :

```
\COPY demo_product(product_name, barcode, folder, grouping, kind, image_name) FROM '/root/SKU110K_fixed/SKU110K_CVPR19/__Iran SKU Dataset 990529 - Bank118.com.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

and I get:

```
/root/SKU110K_fixed/SKU110K_CVPR19/__Iran SKU Dataset 990529 - Bank118.com.csv: Permission denied
```

But as I said the permission of this file is :

> -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2906013 Aug 23 05:58 '__Iran SKU Dataset 990529 - Bank118.com.csv'

My question is why this is happening?
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the owner of this file is **root** and it is placed under *root home directory* which other users don't have access to this directory.

I suggest moving the file to another temporary location, perhaps `/home` directory.

If you saw the error again, change ownership of the file to `postgres` using `chown` command and make sure file permission is at least `640`.

Comment: So what's the usage of -rwxrwxrwx permission for this file?. It says that all the other users can read, write and execute this file

Comment: @K47 : to reach the file, the psql-copy command also has to traverse the /root and /root/SKU110K_fixed/ **directories** . Traversing a directory requires an `x` bit on the directory. (minamally `0711` But a normal user should not be able to get into another users directory tree. Put the file somewhere else (e.g. /data or /tmp)